# Passing data from controller to route in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to figure out how data received from a controller can be used in a different route in Ember.js.

I've got a controller like this, which is making an Ajax call and upon success, calls the `successCallback` function:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  ...
  function successCallback(json){
    var userData = json;
    self.transitionToRoute('dashboard');
  }
  ...
});
```

I'm trying to retrieve this `userData` in LoginController and use it in the dashboard view.

```
App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.controllerFor('login').get('userData');
  }
});
```

I've tried consoling out the results of `this.controllerFor('login').get('userData');` but nothing returns. But consoling out the data before transitioning in the LoginController shows that the data did get assigned to the variable `userData`.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var userData = json;`

declares `userData` as a local variable, which loses scope once you leave the method. You need to have a `userData` property on the controller and then set it using

`this.set('userData', value);`

Then, the value will persist and be available in the dashboard route.

See a working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zojufiheya/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks a lot @kalman-hazins! That worked perfectly. Definitely makes sense about the scope.